# Draw a real-time state graph in HTML5/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**Background:**

I have a set of dependencies that form a "workflow". Each dependency is a node that has a particular state (e.g. idle, waiting, loading, complete, ...)

I wish to represent these dependencies and their current states as a diagram on my website, where there is a label to the node and the colour of the node represents the sate the node is in. The dependencies aren't fixed so the diagram has to be drawn at runtime.

I already have a way to push state updates from my workflow server to my website.

**Question:**

Does HTML5 have anything inbuilt that will allow to do the above (draw the graph and its state changes)? Is there an external library I should use?

Must work in Chrome (don't care about other browsers)

It would be nice to have it auto layed out too so it is readable...

Comment: This is really a better fit for softwarerecs.stackexchange than it is for StackOverflow. For example: 
http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2323/javascript-framework-to-create-flow-like-diagrams

Answer (score 0):

May JointJS solve your problem.

http://www.jointjs.com/

> JointJS is a modern HTML 5 JavaScript library for visualization and interaction with diagrams and graphs. It can be used to create either static diagrams or, and more importantly, fully interactive diagramming tools and application builders. JointJS makes it easy to create visual tools of various kinds.

There are some good examples here http://jointjs.com/demos/fsa

Answer (score 0):

You also may want to check out [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) 
It provides a javascript api to interact with svg elements for drawing anything that you want, but it especially excels at associating data with various properties of drawn elements.

Plus, the documentation is excellent, and there are tons and tons of examples.